# `cut -d: -f5-` prints lines even if they have no colon

Tags: command-line, cut-command

Assuming a file named "file" containing the lines:

```
foo:bar:baz:qux:quux
one:two:three:four:five:six:seven
alpha:beta:gamma:delta:epsilon:zeta:eta:theta:iota:kappa:lambda:mu
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

If we use the cut command with these options we get:

```
$ cut -d ":" -f 5- file
quux
five:six:seven
epsilon:zeta:eta:theta:iota:kappa:lambda:mu
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

In the last line the colon character wasn't found so normally it shouldn't have taken that line because we begin with the 5th field to the end of line.

Why is that so ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default `cut` with the `-f` option prints any line that doesn't contain a delimiter character. Use `-s` if you don't want them:

```
$ cut -d ":" -f 5- -s file
quux
five:six:seven
epsilon:zeta:eta:theta:iota:kappa:lambda:mu
```